# A word for a poor student striving to attend his expensive dream college free of debt

Tags: single-word-requests

Please resolve this argument I have been having with my brother:

A poor student wishes to attend his dream college, despite the yearly costs of $60,000. He has no scholarships and no money saved up to date, but he believes he can raise the money with private donors and scholarships before the fall and attend the school free of debt.

Would this student be considered an idealist? Or any other words to describe this student?

Example sentence:

He is a (an) ___________ who thinks it is possible to attend college free of debt even though he doesn't have any savings nor scholarship.

Comment: At this point (21:50 EDT 01/22/16) to be more helpful, we would have to evaluate the student's plan.  We'd also have to know his field and the college and whether he had been admitted.  All this is beyond ELU.  Thus, I have voted to close.  I suggest the student proceed with his entrepreneurial plans, investigate student loans, and analyze why his dream college is his dream.

Comment: I didn't vote to close but I'd have to agree with ab2 that this is beyond the scope of EL&U. By the way, I was also like your brother -- got into my dream college, no aid (meanwhile aid at other schools). Thanks to the extreme sacrifices of my parents, and others, I made it thru college debt-free. Looking back, I may have been more reasonable but dreams do come true, and I'm an optimist just like he :)

Comment: @ab2 Hi, ab2. I edited the question and please take a look if it reads more on-topic than before. Hi, Eric. Please see if the edit is Okay. If you don't like it, you can roll back.

Comment: If you want a phrase that conveys your belief that the student's plan has no chance of working, then **delusional person** would fit the bill quite nicely (or just **delusional** if you're willing to modify your sentence slightly so it works with an adjective instead of a noun).

Comment: @Rathony I see a real person with a real problem that is not going to be solved by a word.  The problem is going to be solved by a plan (and not a rigid plan) his energy level and his resilience. Whether this person is an idealist, a dreamer, a fantasist,  an unreasonable optimist or a wishful thinker we have no way of knowing.   The best thing he can be is an energetic idealist with charisma and brains and enough pragmatism to gauge the instant (which may never come) to go to Plan B.  The ironic thing is that if he is the top of the top in a techie field, he may not graduate

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [**fantasist**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fantasist) (noun):

Someone who often has ​fantasies, or who ​confuses ​fantasy and what is ​real.(Cambridge Dictionary)

Also [**fantasiser**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fantasiser) (noun):

A person who fantasizes, a fantasist. (The Free Dictionary)

[**fantasize**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fantasize) (verb):

To imagine that you are doing something which is very pleasant or exciting, but which is very unlikely to happen. (Longman Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is appropriate to call someone who is just optimistic with false sense of reality an *idealist*. He is rather a **wishful thinker** who indulges in [wishful thinking](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wishful%20thinking):

> an attitude or belief that something you want to happen will happen
>   even though it is not likely or possible

[Idealist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/idealist) has their own idea, philosophy, or idealism with which they seek to make their community, society or country a more ideal and better place.

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Agreed. Although, in this case, certainly this student's ideals are driving his determination to succeed.

Comment: @TimWard It would depend on how difficult it is for a college student to raise money from private donors (The OP commented under David Blomstrom's answer). I believe it is not very easy based on my own experience.

Comment: I disagree on that point. Our ideals drive our determination; whether it is optimistic or pessimistic in viewpoint is irrelevant. An idealist may believe everyone *should* strive to earn their undergraduate degree without burdensome debt, while the optimist will believe everyone *can*.

Comment: @TimWard Actually I voted to close the question, but retracted it after editing it as I believe the question is related with English Language and its Usage even though is it not an **ideal** question. I think I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

**No, he is not an idealist**. An idealist is [defined by Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idealist) as "one guided by ideals; especially :  one that places ideals before practical considerations." The problem here is that the student is not so much a person who places ideals before practical considerations; rather, he seems to *think* that he is guided by practical considerations, but there is a very high likelihood that he is mistaken. So no, not an idealist. Note that most self-professed idealists are well aware that they are idealists, and will often consciously allow their idealism to govern their actions, knowing that they are likely to be futile or impractical, but doing them just the same as a symbolic gesture, act of protest, or as a means of proving their commitment to their idealistic causes to themselves and to others. This case is completely different: who would knowingly allow their college and life plans to be sabotaged in such an obvious way out of idealism? No one, that's who. And what is the ideal that would be thus expressed? There simply isn't any.

Now that we agree he is not an idealist, the options I think are the best ones are:

- a **wishful thinker** (proposed in @Rathony's answer) - great answer, pretty much nails it.
- a **delusional person** - would be appropriate if you are looking for a phrase that conveys the strong belief that the student's plan has no or little chance of success. It carries obvious negative connotations.
- a **dreamer** (proposed in David Blomstrom's answer) - this *may* be appropriate, and to me sounds like somewhere in between "wishful thinker" and "idealist", but is certainly more correct than idealist. It usually has somewhat positive connotations, so if you want to convey the feeling that the student's plan is somewhat admirable even if highly impractical, this would be a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

No.

He's an ***unreasonable optimist***.

You will recall Shaw:

> The reasonable man adapts himself to the world: the unreasonable one persists in trying to adapt the world to himself. Therefore all progress depends on the unreasonable man.

Comment: Can't an unreasonable optimist be considered a dreamer or idealist?

Comment: @EricLewis: Of course. He or she can also be a blond Pole, a German redhead, a lanky Swahili fellow, a Japanese skier with the center of mass two inches below the navel, or a Texan ranger in a cowboy hat. So what.

Comment: Did Eric Lewis deserve such a rude and ill-considered response? The *person* (because Lewis is not a bot) politely asked you a question, and this is how you normally treat others? Oh, wait. Don't tell me. It's your brand of humour.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It was a perfectly polite, friendly answer. Don't be such a party pooper.

Comment: Never one to admit you may have crossed the line, are you?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: When I'm provoked ... no, let me rephrase it. When I'm exasperated to the point of telling a person exactly what I think of their thoughts and aspirations, yes, I can occasionally cross the line. This does not happen very often. In this case the line wasn't even anywhere in sight. Please believe me. I don't know what gave you that idea. You puzzle me sometimes.